# How to read data from property file and store it in cache node in ibm mb

Tags: ibm-integration-bus

I am completely new to IBM MB, i would want to know how to read data from property file and store in cache node. I have gone through Ibm sites, i could find its possible but i do not know how to implement it. Could someone show me a sample code to read data from property file and store it in cache node and refresh it for every 1 hour.

My property file will be like

```
Key   value
Id1     test1
Id2     test2
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this blog post: [Using the global cache in WebSphere Message Broker](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/1307_pal/1307_pal.html)

This article showed a sample implementation of the new WebSphere Message Broker global cache feature in an enterprise environment to store and access reference data. The global cache is useful in many other scenarios, and you can write similar ESQL and Java routines to access the global cache depending on your requirements.